# Info button not linking to other view controller

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton, segue

I have an info button that appears as an overlay UIView on top of a camera view that is not linking to the desired view controller.  Nothing happens when it is touched.

Here is the code to create the button and link it

```
    // Create a Button to get Help
    infoButton =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight ] ;
    CGRect buttonRect = infoButton.frame;

    // Calculate the bottom right corner
    buttonRect.origin.x = 455;
    buttonRect.origin.y = 297;
    [infoButton setFrame:buttonRect];

    [infoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(presentInfo) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [view addSubview:infoButton];
```

Here is the code to create segue

```
- (void) presentInfo
{
InfoViewController *ivc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"InfoViewController"];
[self presentModalViewController:ivc animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Try dismissing the camera, and calling for the view change in the cameras dismissal completion handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this first:
- Set a breakpoint in:

```
- (void) presentInfo
{
InfoViewController *ivc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"InfoViewController"];
[self presentModalViewController:ivc animated:YES];
}
```

if the program reach this point it must be a problem with the segue.

I had some problems with button this week too. In my case there once was an other UIView over my button, so it doesn't hit the selector.
Or you can try and change:

```
[infoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(presentInfo) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

In:

```
[infoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(presentInfo) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

Also look if the button react to your touch with the alternative image.

I hope this helps

Oh or try and give it a UITapGestureRecognizer you make, but this is only for the real desperate solution, if nothing else works...

Comment: Thanks for the tip! There was a problem in my selector.  Breakpoint solution was helpful